# Complex Analysis and showing that in disk $(0,1)$, $f(z)= sin\ z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_n$ be a sequence of distinct points in $D(0, 1)$ such that $z_n → 0$ and let $f : D(0, 1) → {\mathbb C}$ be holomorphic. Show
that if $f(z_n) = sin \ z_n$ for all $n$, then $f(z) = sin\ z$ for all $z \in D(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(z) - \sin z$ is identically zero on the set $\{z_n\}$ and furthermore $f(0) - \sin 0 = 0$ since $f$ is holomorphic on $D$. It follows $f(z) - \sin z$ is identically zero on a set with an accumulation point and thus is identically zero on $D$. The [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) implies $f(z) = \sin z$ on $D$.